# Qpid for python , Not able to subscribe for a topic

Tags: python, activemq-classic, qpid, jms-topic

Using Qpid for python, I am using the Container to connect to ActiveMq with the connector URL as:
username:password@hostname:5672/topicName. 
In the web console i can see that for AMQP the connection is up . But instead of subscribing to existing topic it create a new queue with that name .

Can someone help me in the format which has to be given to subscribe for a topic. Or if i am missing something please point me in right direction.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the Qpid for python URI syntax but from the ActiveMQ side a destination is addressed directly by using a destination prefix.  For a topic the prefix is topic:// and for queue it is queue:// unsurprisingly.  In the absence of a prefix the broker defaults the address in question to a Queue type as that is generally the preference.

So to fix your issue you need to construct a URI that uses the correct prefix which in your case would be something using topic://some-name and that should get you the results you expect.

Comment: I had tried with the prefix topic:// but didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the issue was , In On_start method we have to use event.container.create_receiver() and the URL has to be in format topic://